# How to setup shibboleth for saml azure ad

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, shibboleth, shibboleth-sp

Hey I have given a task to setup shibboleth to authenticate my web application ( .net core application (SP) ) using saml 2.0 with azure ad. My web application will act as SP and will manipulate the claims/attributes returned from IDP which is azure ad in my case. I have made a research but could not find any relevant documentation or implementation example of configuring shibboleth as a SP for saml authentication using azure ad as  (IDP). Can we setup shibboleth to support saml 2.0 with azure ad? Also I am wondering after successful authentication how claims/attributes will pass from shibboleth to my application so that I can further use them for processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this blog> [Azure AD SAML federation using Shibboleth SP | by Rohan Islam | Medium](https://rohanislam2.medium.com/azure-ad-saml-federation-using-shibboleth-sp-ad40f9c94eab) can be worked around in your case.

> 1. Configure the SAML SSO in azure ad portal for the application by selecting Single sign on and Copy the identities to use later.
> 2. Try to do Shibboleth SP configuration by updating shibboleth2.xml file under /etc/shibboleth directory.
> 3. Update the applications’s entity ID , session lifetime configuration .Also change sso entity  ID with the azure AD generated
>    entity ID.
> 4. Generate SP Metadata by accessing the metatdata url and by making the required changes .This SP metadata xml file is to be uploaded in
>    sso page of azure ad  under mange identity section.

All the mapped attributes will be stored in the session so that you can access them in your application.
SP makes [attribute](https://wiki.cac.washington.edu/display/infra/Configure+a+Service+Provider+to+Use+Attributes) and other session information available to applications is by "exporting" the data to a set of environment variables or HTTP request headers using HTTP_ PREFIX

**References:**

1. [NativeSPAttributeAccess (atlassian.net)](https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SHIB2/pages/2577072162/NativeSPAttributeAccess#NativeSPAttributeAccess-EnvironmentVariables)
2. [How to read attributes? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500489/shibboleth-how-to-read-attributes/18507127#18507127) or [NativeSPAddAttribute - Shibboleth 2 - Confluence (atlassian.net)](https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SHIB2/pages/2577072493/NativeSPAddAttribute)
3. [c# - asp.net MVC authentication with Shibboleth - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718012/asp-net-mvc-authentication-with-shibboleth)